# Aggregator of type top_hits cannot accept sub-aggregations with Percentiles

Tags: elasticsearch, nested, aggregation

I have the following documents:

```
{"id": 1, "type": "bags", "brand": "Louis Vuitton", "condition": "new", "price": 500}
{"id": 2, "type": "bags", "brand": "Louis Vuitton", "condition": "new", "price": 450}
{"id": 3, "type": "bags", "brand": "Louis Vuitton", "condition": "new", "price": 420}

{"id": 4, "type": "bags", "brand": "Louis Vuitton", "condition": "like new", "price": 150}
{"id": 5, "type": "bags", "brand": "Louis Vuitton", "condition": "like new", "price": 150}
{"id": 6, "type": "bags", "brand": "Louis Vuitton", "condition": "like new", "price": 100}

{"id": 7, "type": "bags", "brand": "Louis Vuitton" "condition": "used", "price": 400}
{"id": 8, "type": "bags", "brand": "Louis Vuitton", "condition": "used", "price": 350}
{"id": 9, "type": "bags", "brand": "Louis Vuitton", "condition": "used", "price": 300}
```

I am looking to write a query that will return to me the Percentiles of prices for the top 2 documents for each condition. In other words, I want to perform some calculation after getting the top 2 best scoring documents for each item condition (new, like new, used). I have tried this but I am getting the error the error `Aggregator of type top_hits cannot accept sub-aggregations`:

```
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "brand": "Louis Vuitton"
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "item_conditions": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "condition"
            },
            "aggs": {
                "top_two": {
                    "top_hits": {
                        "size": 2
                    },
                    "aggs": {
                        "top_two_percentiles": {
                            "percentiles": {
                                "field": "price"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there another way to achieve this, or do I have to do some post-processing myself after getting the results back from ES? The end result I want is to be able to supply this data to charts to make it look like this: https://ibb.co/y5FpV80

Comment: `Percentiles of prices for the top 2 documents` doesn't have any statistical value

Answer (score 0):

"... the percentiles of prices for the **top two** documents ..." is somewhat arbitrary. What's the metric that determines the score? A `terms` aggregation would score the buckets equally. The only differentiating factor would be the bucket count... What I'm saying is, you'll need to first determine **what** puts a given bucket in the top 2 and go from there.

In any event, you can:

1. Order any `terms` aggregation [by the result of one of its numeric child aggregations](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation-order).
2. After that, you can limit it to 2 buckets.
3. When that's done, you can use a [percentiles bucket aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-percentiles-bucket-aggregation.html) to calculate the percentiles of the two top prices.

In concrete terms:

```json
POST your-index/_search?filter_path=aggregations.*.buckets.key,aggregations.*.buckets.doc_count,aggregations.*.buckets.percentiles_top_two_prices
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "brand": "Louis Vuitton"
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "item_conditions": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "condition"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "top_two": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "price",
            "size": 2,
            "order": {
              "max_score": "desc"       <-- here's how you enforce the top 2 docs
            }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "max_score": {
              "max": {
                "script": "_score"      <-- how you determine what happens here is up to you. _score will be equal across all buckets (I believe) so pick some other metric.
              } 
            },
            "just_the_price": {
              "min": {
                "field": "price"        <-- there's no "identity" agg in ES so I'm using min. There will be only bucket because you're already under the parent which aggregates the price.
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "percentiles_top_two_prices": {
          "percentiles_bucket": {
            "buckets_path": "top_two>just_the_price"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

yielding something along the lines of:

```json
{
  "aggregations" : {
    "item_conditions" : {
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "like new",
          "doc_count" : 3,
          "percentiles_top_two_prices" : {
            "values" : {
              "1.0" : 100.0,
              "5.0" : 100.0,
              "25.0" : 100.0,
              "50.0" : 150.0,
              "75.0" : 150.0,
              "95.0" : 150.0,
              "99.0" : 150.0
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : "new",
          "doc_count" : 3,
          "percentiles_top_two_prices" : {
            "values" : {
              "1.0" : 420.0,
              "5.0" : 420.0,
              "25.0" : 420.0,
              "50.0" : 450.0,
              "75.0" : 450.0,
              "95.0" : 450.0,
              "99.0" : 450.0
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : "used",
          "doc_count" : 3,
          "percentiles_top_two_prices" : {
            "values" : {
              "1.0" : 300.0,
              "5.0" : 300.0,
              "25.0" : 300.0,
              "50.0" : 350.0,
              "75.0" : 350.0,
              "95.0" : 350.0,
              "99.0" : 350.0
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I'm frankly not sure what these stats would bring you (when based on only two values) but this is how it could be done